# Land masking and Fast Fourier transformation

Tags: ocean

I want to create a land masking for a netcdf file I have that contains information about the horizontal velocity on the Gulf Stream. So I want to have only oceanic points. I am attaching info for the nc file down here. Any ideas about the land masking?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcLHN.png)

Comment: I am not sure I follow. Do you just want to create a file which has 0/1 values with 1 being land, 0 the ocean?

Comment: Yes exactly. I want to mask the land points of the gulf stream region.. In the photo you may see the dimensions , coordinates, variables